# Efficient algorithm for communicating vessels

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to make most efficient algorithm to solve problem of communicating vessels.

```
Input:
Number of vessels (int, 1-200000)
For each vessel - altitude of vessel (int, can be negative)
                  height (int, >1)
                  width (int, >1)
                  depth (int, >1)
Volume of water (int >=0, read to EOF)

Output:
Altitude of water surface (double) or "Empty" or "Overflow"
```

I made a program (in C), that use the bisection method but it sometimes doesn't give the right results (f.e. vessels 1 1 1 1 and 3 3 3 3 and volume 1 gives 2.25 instead of 2.0, or overflow detection problem).

So my algorithm is:

- Read values
- Convert them `(altitude of bottom, altitude of top, area)`
- `qsort (altitude of bottom)`
- `SURFACE = (lowest + highest place)/2`
- Compute volume from bottom to `SURFACE`
- Is volume equal to desired volume (allow error 0.000001)? Is greater or smaller than desired volume?
- If greater take bottom half and repeat process, if smaller take upper, save computed volume, repeat process.

I hope it is understandable.

Is there better method to solve this? Or how to improve my method?

Picture of input:

[image: image of input]

Comment: Since you're working with floating point values, you might want to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Besides that, run the program in a debugger, and step through the code line by line while keeping track of variables and their values. It might help you find if something is odd.

Comment: Your question should be self-contained. It should fully explain the problem you are trying to solve. I don't know what the "problem of communicating vessels" is, so from your explanation and image I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: The problem of this method is it simply can't determine right altitude if there is no alt intersestion between vessels. By this method, result in example is right, but not ideal, because right is also 2.20, 2.05 etc.

Answer (score 1):

If we have the same liquid in the system (so the density of liquids in vessels are the same) - the level in all communicating vessels will be the same.

**Step 1.** let's calculate some not-changing parameters: the volume of liquid before experiment and the lowest level:

V<sub>before</sub> = SUM(H<sub>i</sub>*W<sub>i</sub>), where H<sub>i</sub> is height in vessel i and W<sub>i</sub> is width of vessel i.

L<sub>lowest</sub> = MIN(A<sub>i</sub> + D<sub>i</sub>), where A<sub>i</sub> is altitude of vessel i and D<sub>i</sub> is depth of vessel i

The basic equation will be the law of saving volumes (before and after the system is set free):

V<sub>before</sub> = V<sub>after</sub> + V<sub>overflow</sub>

Plus the following obvious conditions must be met:

V<sub>overflow</sub> > 0 if L<sub>result</sub> > L<sub>lowest</sub>

V<sub>overflow</sub> = 0 if L<sub>result</sub> <= L<sub>lowest</sub>

Based on that, we can set the first level, for example, as arithmetic average of levels before and then calculate the difference, check V<sub>overflow</sub>, and if doesn't meet conditions, increase and decrease level and reiterate.

**Step 2.**  But I have another idea. Let's check the case when the system is just about the overflow:

V<sub>overflow</sub> = 0

L<sub>result</sub> = L<sub>lowest</sub>

V<sub>after</sub> = SUM((L<sub>result</sub> - A<sub>i</sub>)*W<sub>i</sub>), but of course for those i where (L<sub>result</sub> - A<sub>i</sub>) > 0 because obviously vessel can't hold negative amount of liquid.

And as a result we will have three possible cases:

If V<sub>after</sub> = V<sub>before</sub>, then L<sub>result</sub> is what we are looking for.

If V<sub>after</sub> > V<sub>before</sub>, then no overflow occurred and simple reallocation of liquid between vessels occurred. So, we can calculate the result level as:

L<sub>result</sub> = V<sub>before</sub>/SUM(W<sub>i</sub>), for those i where (L<sub>result</sub> - A<sub>i</sub>) > 0

If V<sub>after</sub> < V<sub>before</sub>, then overflow occurred and L<sub>result</sub> = L<sub>lowest</sub>. The difference V<sub>before</sub> - V<sub>after</sub> left the system from the open end of the lowest vessel.

Comment: @JakubČech I was too optimistic with the previous solution, hehe ~),